# Path location of the image cannot locate in Eclipse swt

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I have a problem when exporting my java project. It cannot find the path of my image.

- File Project

  - src
  - config
  - image

    - copy.png

This is where my image is located

```
String image1 = "image/copy.png";
shell.setImage(new Image(display, image1));
```

It works before i export but when i export it and update my program it gives me an error. I tried also to use `InputStream` but it gives me null.

Comment: The path you have is relative so will need a prefix of some sort. Also, how are you exporting? As files, as a jar?

Comment: Exporting as a jar.

Comment: So is the image being exported into the jar or are you only exporting class files? If it is a resource, ie within the jar, you will need to load as a resource within the jar. Look into the jar with a rar or zip program.

Comment: When i'm selecting what will be inside the jar I'm clicking main Folder which is the File project where the folders are already inside

Comment: Yeah, but during the export steps it asks which file types to export. You may not be exporting the image into the jar. And if the file is in the jar, you will need to retrieve it as a resource in your code as the link explains: https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/

Comment: I tried to use what you give me the link but it still cant find the path

Comment: Navigate into the jar file with winzip or winrar to confirm whether it contains the image file. That is the first step.

Comment: i zip the jar file and then it contains the image

Comment: What type of Image class are you using? It probably doesn't understand jar packaging to load the file.

Comment: what do you mean by image class?

Comment: new Image(...) - what is the class of Image? like java.lang.String

Comment: `import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;` is this what you saying?

Comment: Indeed, I have provided roughly what should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the specified class, org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image, you will want to create the Image with method Image(Device device, InputStream stream) and use getClass().getResourceAsStream( image1 )  to supply the inputStream containing the file. You probably need "/" at the start of your path.

Comment: I will try this.

Comment: Have you had any success with this?

Answer (score -1):

Create image with this method work well.

```
new Image(device, getClass().getResourceAsStream(localImagePath));
```